# Django 2 поля отношений многие к одному

Tags: django, field

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с помощью каких полей в Django 2 можно это реализовать:

Есть класс keywords, где лежит список ключевых слов

Есть класс Articles, где есть список статей на сайте

Соответсвенно, одно ключевое слово может принадлежать только к одной статье, но для одной статьи может быть несколько ключевых слов.

Как сделать так, чтобы после того, как ключевое слово было выбрано для одной статьи, для другой статьи его уже нельзя было выбрать?

Comment: Я так понимаю ближе всего сюда подходит ForeignKey с unique=True?

Answer (score 0):

Все просто, у вас поле ManyToMany field?Чтобы выбрать несколько ключевых слов(я так понимаю у вас на сайте у статьи есть типо теги) просто зажмите control
[image: Я просто зажал control и выбрал соответствующие теги]

Comment: Да, у меня сейчас сделано ManyToMany. Хотелось бы сделать так, что когда я для одной статьи выбрал теги "Политика" и "ООН", для другой статьи эти теги уже нельзя было выбрать. Например, их бы уже просто не было в списке. Или хотя бы они были помечены другим цветом.

Comment: Дайте ваши views.py, именно создание поста во вьюхах.